# Is the following Java variable declaration valid?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax

I mistakenly declared an array of strings as follows:

```
String[] tokens[];
```

Eclipse does not highlight this as an error but instead considers it to be equivalent to:

```
String[][] tokens;
```

Is this correct behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct behaviour - arrays can be defined with brackets after either the object type **or** variable name.

```
String[] tokens;
```

and

```
String tokens[];
```

are the same.  It is however a confusing way to write a 2D array so I wouldn't deliberately use it ;)

If you think of arrays as Objects (Which they technically are) and the square brackets as syntactic sugar for the new keyword and an empty contructor you could envisage your "error" as:

```
tokens = new Array<String>(new Array<String>());
```

as both

```
String[] tokens;
```

and

```
String tokens[];
```

would both be equivalent to

```
new Array<String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's correct beahviour. These are equivalent:

```
String[] tokens[];
String tokens[][];
String[][] tokens;
```

For clarity you should declare the "[]"s on the variable type, not on its name, but other than that it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid declaration. You could also declare it like `String tokens[][];`

Answer (score 1):

Trust Eclipse. All of the following are equivalents:

```
String tokens[][];
String[] tokens[];
String [][]tokens;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), you can (but conventionally should not) declare arrays with square brackets after the variable name:

> You can also place the square brackets after the array's name:
>
> ```
> // this form is discouraged
> float anArrayOfFloats[];
> ```
>
> However, convention discourages this form; the brackets identify the
>   array type and should appear with the type designation.

Given this and your observations, it's safe to say that Eclipse allows you to mix those forms of declarations, which in your case results in an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reminiscence of older languages like C/C++.

Actually, for how type checking and JVM works in Java the declaration

```
String[][] tokens;
```

is more coherent.

This because you are declaring `tokens` with the type of "bidimensional array of `String` objects" so `String[][]` can be considered a single type declaration.